# When is "onEnter" exactly executed

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm looking for a best way to redirect my users from login/register form if they are already properly authenticated (and vice-versa)

So is it a good idea to do it onEnter? Will that function be executed before the associated controllers? Example:

```
...
.state('auth', {
    templateUrl: "auth.html",
    controller: 'PBAuthController as PBAuth',
    onEnter:  skipIfLoggedIn
})
...
function skipIfLoggedIn($q, $auth, $state) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    if ($auth.isAuthenticated()) {
        $state.go('backend');
    } else {
        deferred.resolve();
    }
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: there are plenty of good articles that describe how to do this in angular, usually using interceptors and `$routeChangeStart` or `$stateChangeStart`.  For example, http://www.frederiknakstad.com/2013/01/21/authentication-in-single-page-applications-with-angular-js/, or https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/techniques-for-authentication-in-angularjs-applications-7bbf0346acec#.kf8mshm66, or http://blog.thesparktree.com/post/75952317665/angularjs-interceptors-globally-handle-401-and

Comment: @Phil i tried but i can't see :D i'm still building the backend part of the app so i can't be 100% sure that this is the way to go.

Comment: @Claies thanks, will check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did a quick test and `onEnter` fires before the controller however there doesn't appear to be any way to prevent the controller from being instantiated.

In any case, here's how I've handled redirects in `onEnter`. The only thing to watch out for is to not interrupt the current state transition. You do this by waiting for the [`$state.transition`](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state#properties_transition) promise to resolve...

```
onEnter: function($state, $auth) {
    return $auth.isAuthenticated() && $state.transition.then(function() {
        return $state.go('backend');
    });
}
```